# Removing more than one white-space

Tags: php, removing-whitespace

So, If I have a string like

```
"hello    what is  my    name"
```

How can I take all of the spaces and replace each with only one space?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text);
```

**Output:**

```
hello what is my name
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution:

```
<?php

$str = ' This is    a    test   ';
$count = 1;
while($count)
    $str = str_replace('  ', ' ', $str, $count);

?>
```

Comment: That's not really the most elegant solution... infact it's quite inefficient.

Comment: Good solution for one who aren't familiar with regular expressions. And "efficiency" doesn't really matter here.

Comment: Wow, it's funny to look back at how much worse I sucked years ago.

Comment: Wow, it's funny to look back at how much I thought I sucked 5 years ago considering how much I still sucked at the time.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:-**

```
$desc = "hello    what is  my    name";
echo trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $desc));
```